# Real world effects of a modern day superhero?

Tags: earth, gods, super-powers

Suddenly on the news, reports indicate a god-like superhero with immense powers (equivalent to Superman or Jesus) has just prevented a large natural disaster, defeated a terrorist organisation and overthrown a tyrannical government all in a single night. The world is shocked to say the least. The next day everything changes. Nerds have brain orgasms, government officials poop their pants, scientists gaze in awe and the religious declare that the end of the world is now upon us.

What steps shall the world take in dealing with this immortal godlike being and how does his presence effect the way we live out our lives for future generations to come?

Comment: this has the potential to be very very broad, so you may want to specify the question a bit, but beyond that this hero will be worshipped as god by a lot, and there will be those saying its a bad idea and that us humans cant stop them if they go rogue

Comment: This question is basically story generation. You are proposing a scenario, and asking the answerer to finish the story. There is no criteria proposed for determine what answer is correct. This site is for more specific questions. For example, you could propose a set of reactions, and ask if those are realistic. I am voting to close this question as 'primary opinion based.'

Comment: I am not religious, but calling Jesus a superhero may be offensive, apart from being completely inaccurate, to believers in Christianity. You should have stuck with Superman as your superhero template. This question could be improved if you were specific about the powers and abilities of your real-life superhero (and any limitations or weaknesses), then it is possible to estimate the impact on the world.

Answer (score 3):

If a Superman-like being emerged overnight and "prevented a large natural disaster, defeated a terrorist organisation and overthrown a tyrannical government", then governments and people around the world be trying to get in contact with the aforementioned super-being. They would want to know what he was going to next and what were his future plans. Because they would want to know how this was going to affect their lives.

Basically everyone would want to negotiate and accommodate with the super-being. They would also want to know where he hangs his cape when he's not out and about doing his superheroics.

Persons, organizations and governments that will find themselves in contradiction with whatever he wants to do with set about trying to find ways to destroy the super-being. After all, everybody needing a bargaining chip in any negotiation.

It is frankly impossible to determine what future generations will do because this is entirely contingent on what the super-being intends to do, and the question does not supply any information about that. It is possible to assume the super-being will do what Superman does, but Superman is a fictional character whose exploits are limited to what his writers can imagine and fairly limited ways. A real-life super-being will have ideas of his own and there is no reason to assume they will duplicate a fictional Superman's.

All that can be said, is to guess what the initial reactions will be to the arrival of a real-life super-being. Beyond that, is pure speculation. Otherwise you need to be specific: the details of the natural disaster, what terrorist organization was defeated, and which tyrannical government was overthrown. These will begin to give ideas about some of what the super-being's activities will be. Some guesses can be made initially, but after that it's nothing but guesswork.